# getElementById inside a div

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm using a Javascript to change the text on a form submit button, this is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  document.getElementById("button").value="New Button Text";
});
</script>
```

The code work perfectly, but I need to change it so that it effects the id `#button` within a div with the id of `#formwrap`. So basically I need to `.getElementById("button")` contained within the div with a id of `#formwrap`

Comment: Does that mean that you have another element with ID `#button`? If so, you should keep in mind that IDs should be unique across one page.

Comment: I know, the problem is, this is a Google form implemented on the site. Google forms are used across the site and the different forms need different button text, but all of the forms have the same IDs and Classes. So I'm trying to get around the problem by wrapping each form in a div with a unique ID.

Comment: Then you could target the contents by tagname '#divId button'

Comment: Still with the getElementById? Because that doesn't seem to work, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("#formwrap #button").value="New Button Text";`

Also doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using jquery, why not just do

```
$('#formwrap #button').val('New Button Text');
```

?

It's simply CSS-like selector, similar to what you'd use in `querySelectorAll()`.

It will match for example this button:

```
<div id="formwrap"><input type="button" id="button"></div>
```

But keep in mind that only one element can have the same ID.

Maybe you wanted class? Then you'd use `.button` instead of `#button`.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, however I tend to see that your solution doesn't *REALLY* help to give the OP understanding about meaning of element IDs in one DOM structure. *UPD:* Good that you added the explanation +1.

Comment: `$('#formwrap #button').val('New Button Text');` is not working...

You're right, the button should have a class, which would make my life a lot easier, but the problem is, this is a Google form implemented on the site. Google forms are used across the site and the different forms need different button text, but all of the forms have the same IDs and Classes. So I'm trying to get around the problem by wrapping each form in a div with a unique ID.

Ps. I didn't downvote you either.